# Flutter - Is it possible to unselect all items on bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter project.  I have a bottomNavigationBar, style=fixed. It has 4 items and it works fine.  However, I need a way to unselect all items on this bar.  It seems that it has to always have exactly 1 item selected, which generally makes sense, but for my project there are some instances where I need to have 0 items selected.

I can fake this by changing the color of the icon and text to be the same color of the inactive items, and that pretty much looks inactive, except the icon and text are slightly larger since it really is still selected.

Is there a way to actually unselect all items in a bottomNavigationBar instead of just trying to make them appear to be unselected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61802030/display-bottom-navigation-bar-but-none-of-its-item-is-selected/74008475#74008475 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182384/flutter-how-to-hide-remove-title-of-bottomnavigationbaritem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to set all bottom navbar items as unselected. At a time, one of them should be set as selected.

As you also suggested, the only workaround is to make all items look like "unselected" by setting style properties like `selectedItemColor`, etc. of `BottomNavigationBar`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is impossible but there is a trick:

```
int _selectedIndex = -1;// Unselect any item

....

bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
  // This is all you need!
  items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.support),
      label: 'support',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.business),
      label: 'business',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.text_snippet_sharp),
      label: 'Report',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
      label: 'Account',
    ),
  ],
  currentIndex: selectedIndex == -1 ? 0: selectedIndex,
  selectedItemColor: selectedIndex == -1 ? Colors.grey[600] : Colors.amber[800],
  unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[600],
  onTap: onTap,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: getBottomNavigationBarItems(),
        currentIndex: _currentPage < 4 ? _currentPage : 0,
        showSelectedLabels:_currentPage < 4,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    int navIndex = -1;

    showSelectedLabels: navIndex != -1,
    currentIndex: navIndex == -1 ? 0 : navIndex,
    selectedItemColor: navIndex == -1 ? Colors.grey[300] : Colors.white,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey[300],
```